# Adding line WPF control on ToolBox

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, wpf-controls

I need to draw lines and dots (circles) in WFP. (VS 2010)

I tried using Ellipse control for dots, but I don't have the line ones. 
I however added `<Line` element directly in XAML and this worked... 
but how I have the line control in the toolbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click the toolbox, click Choose items (wow that dialog's slow...) look for Line and check it. That's it.

Comment: It really is very slow!

Answer (score 1):

Lots of lesser-used WPF controls don't show up in the toolbox by default.  You have to right-click, and select Choose Items, then find the controls you want to add
[image: toolbox items chooser]